# Can we use different back-end logic (Java & python) for developing a website?

Tags: java, python, web, web-deployment, backend

I am developing a website for downloading songs.It has two interfaces where one is end users and another is for admin.Admin can set the metadata(artist, year of release, rating, genre), to do this I have python eyed3 API.For end users, I have to retrieve songs list based on input provided, to do this  I am using java(since I am familiar), Is it possible to use different programming languages as backend on apache tomcat server?

Comment: Yes: first run the website from a Java or Python web server, and have the back-end invoke Python or Java code.

Comment: do u mean I can invoke python code from java backend?

Comment: Sure, just have Java invoke something like `/home/likhith/hello.py` on the shell.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In java you can use http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/ for editing tag information. Also if you wish you can use some command line utilities which you can execute as background process

Comment: Is it a third party library or is it present in java standard packages?

Comment: Java ID3 tab library is third party library.